# Sharepoint desiger

Tags: sharepoint-designer

How to resolve the **Server side activites have been updated.You need to restart sharepoint designer to use the updated version of activites.** this error in the sharepoint designer.Please help me to sort it out the issue

Answer (score 3):

**Approach 1: Clear the cache folders**

How to Clear Your SharePoint Designer 2010/2013 Cache.

- Navigate to the "File" menu then select "Options" -> "General" -> "Application Options".
- On the “General” tab, under the “General” heading, uncheck “Cache site data across SharePoint Designer sessions”.

If you've just deployed some custom workflow activities to your site, this will probably solve your problem (and you should clear the cache folders every time you deploy custom activities). If the error occurs spontaneously, this approach often won't help.

**Approach 2: Reinstall SharePoint Designer**

This might work if you've got a preview version of SharePoint Designer installed. If not, it's unlikely to help. It didn't work for me, and it didn't work for countless others on the forums.

**Approach 3: Install SharePoint Designer on another machine**

This one kind of annoys me... it usually works, but it's hardly a practical solution to the problem.

*References*

- [Server-side activities have been updated](http://www.jrjlee.com/2014/10/server-side-activities-have-been-updated.html)
- [How to Clear Your SharePoint Designer 2010/2013 Cache](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache/)

Comment: Still no luck same issue persist.

Comment: @user42024 Have you tried this update? I've used this one on my latest Dev-VM https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48546

Comment: I am getting error as expected system was not found on the system.When i am trying to update the software.

Comment: Then uninstall your 64 bit version, and install the 32 bit version.

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstall the version again same error.Server side activites have been updated.You need to restart sharepoint designer to use the updated version of activites

Comment: It worked after unistall the Vs 2017 .